# Wallpapers are merged with multiple images after suspend

Tags: gnome, 14.04, suspend, desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3. I have multiple wallpapers in rotation. When I suspend my computer and I go back, my wallpapers are merged as you can see here :

[image: background merged]

In addition, I can't do a right click on my desktop.

Is there something to do to solve this problem?

Comment: try this `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop background-fade false` or `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop background-fade true`

Comment: It's hard to say if it works. The problem does not occur every time. I will try one setting and another if the problem persist.

Comment: I wonder if both of the pics are from the same directory. I have wally wallpaper switcher, during switching wallpapers it's using a default gnome wallpaper in-between.

Comment: What application are you using to "rotate" the wallpapers?

Comment: While I understand how this could be annoying I have to say that is one of the most beautiful bugs I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. When this happens, try pressing Alt+F2, type `r` and press enter. This will re-initiate your GNOME session without logging out or closing any applications.

Comment: It works but I don't think it's a definitive solution.

Comment: Right, this is only a temporary work-around while the bugs are being worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true` (or `false`)

A site: http://lifehacker.com/5581364/reset-gnome-when-things-go-wrong-on-your-linux-desktop

Or reset your gnome desktop. Hope this helps.